# Not able to execute cgi script getting muxserver_listen bind(): Permission denied

Tags: apache-2.2, perl

When i  run a perl CGI script from browser it gives below error in apache error logs.
It is not getting response from server. While i run my script from command prompt it works fine.

I am using below code in my perl CGI script

```
my %opts = (
    user        => "uname",
    password    => "password",
    ctl_dir     => "/tmp/.libnet-openssh-perl",
    strict_mode => 0,
);

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("192.168.0.201",%opts,master_opts => ['-vvv', -o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" ] );
    $ssh->system("ls /home/sysadmin/") or
     die "remote command failed: " . $ssh->error;
```

Error Logs:

```
[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] debug3: preferred keyboard-interactive,password\r, referer: 
[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] debug3: authmethod_lookup password\r, referer: 
[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] debug3: remaining preferred: ,password\r, referer: 
[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password\r, referer: 
[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] debug1: Next authentication method: password\r, referer: 
[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 62 padlen 18 extra_pad 64)\r, referer: 
[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply\r, referer: 
[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).\r, referer: 
[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] Authenticated to 192.168.0.201 ([192.168.0.201]:22).\r, referer:
[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] debug1: setting up multiplex master socket\r, referer: 
**[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] debug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /tmp/.libnet-openssh-perl/sysadmin-192.168.0.2-28537-877268.LF0y9f2rHmaMBPaq\r, referer: 
[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] muxserver_listen bind(): Permission denied\r, referer: 
[Tue Jul 01 13:05:52 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.136] remote command failed: unable to establish master SSH connection: bad password or master process exited unexpectedly at /var/cgi-bin1/GnipReplay.cgi line 43., referer:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running on RHEL or CentOS SELinux may be blocking scripts from initiating network connections.

Confirm that you're running with SELinux in enforcing mode with `getenforce`.

Test that the problem disappears whith temporarily setting SELinux to permissive mode: `setenforce 0`

If you retry now and your script works you've found the culprit.

Restore SELinux `setenforce 1` and try if setting the one of the SELinux booleans solves your problems. On RHEL/CentOS 6 `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1` is likely one.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Script is working fine now. I have put selinux in permissive mode i.e setenforce=0

Comment: Be aware that `setenforce 0` is not persistent across reboots... And doing so is bad practice, you really need know/learn how to make your scripts with SELinux enabled.

Comment: @Hufeza it is customary to [accept the answer](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) if it proved to be the solution to your problem, as that both closes the question and gives an signal to other people finding your problem one of the answers provided was useful.